# How to use the value of a method result based on a test?

Tags: java, php

I have some Java like this:

```
if (!fooclass.getInfoText().equals(""))
{
    this.setInfoText(fooclass.getInfoText());
}
```

Is there a neater way of setting one value based on the test results of another value? It seems nasty to me that the method is run twice, but putting the result in a variable when it may be empty and not used at all seems equally messy.

In PHP I might do:

```
if (($foo = $bar->baz()) !== "")
{
    $this->set_info_text = $foo;
}
```

But I know some people are quite strongly for and against this method, though I can't recall a good justification against it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe `fooclass` is a reference of `Foo` class. I can only think about introducing a variable and check it to prevent the double-invokation of same method.

```
String fooInfo = fooclass.getInfoText();
if (!"".equals(fooInfo))
{
    this.setInfoText(fooInfo);
}
```

**NOTE**

I'm using `"".equals(fooInfo)` to [avoid NPE](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Preventing_NullPointerException).

Comment: Thanks for the advice on avoiding NPE. So is this your recommended method, using a variable?

Comment: @deed02392 at this moment I can't think of another solution.

Comment: Introducing a variable may be a form of premature optimization. Nevertheless an explaining variable may help readability. I usually do not introduce variables when it's about simple getters, as they are mostly self-explanatory. If setting `infoText`should always be a no-op then perhaps the setter could do the check, but then I'd be inclined to rename the setter to reflect this behavior.

Comment: @bowmore actually he was not happy with invoking same method twice. So I gave this solution & I'm not also very fond of introducing *unwanted* variables.

Comment: Indeed, sometimes these methods are expensive, e.g. when they involve database queries.

Comment: @tintinmj I agree with your solution, it's basically what he'd do in php. I just wanted to clarify what would be a valid reason to introduce a variable, and what would not be.